# Yii booster TbImageColumn - setting Image attributes

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, yii-booster

Is there any way to add other attributes to the image tag generated by `TbImageColoumn` ?

The documentation is not very clear on how to set image attributes like height, width etc. It only mentions on how to add image src using [imagePathExpression](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/extendedGridView/index.html#gridcolumns) attribute,

My current column looks like this

```
           .....
            array(
                'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbImageColumn',
                'imagePathExpression'=>'$data->getImage("large")',
                'usePlaceKitten'=>false,
                ),
           .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging through the code it seems there is an attribute for setting html attributes to the generated tag using the `imageOptions` and to set attributes on generated td cell tag we can use the `htmlOptions` array from the base clase

```
/**
 * TbImageColumn widget class
 *
 * @package booster.widgets.grids.columns
 */
class TbImageColumn extends CGridColumn
{
    /**
     * @var array the HTML options of the image tag
     */
    public $imageOptions = array();
```

so to limit image width to 50px the column should be modified to

```
           .....
            array(
                'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbImageColumn',
                'imagePathExpression'=>'$data->getImage("large")',
                'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'min-width: 50px;'),
                'imageOptions'=>array('width'=>'50px'),
                'usePlaceKitten'=>false,
            ),
           .....
```